# How to optimize dockerfile multi-stage build with ODBC 17 driver installation: review needed

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I am learning Docker and Dockerfile best practices. What is the best way to install system packages with apt-get that serve on at build or run-time by taking advantage of Docker's multi-stage build (in this case `gnupg`, `curl`, and `gcc`)?

This is my Dockerfile (python app) to date:

```
# The base image to build upon my app
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.9.16
ARG DEBIAN_VERSION=bullseye
ARG BASE_IMAGE=python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim-${DEBIAN_VERSION}
# Set virtual enviroment path
ARG VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} as build
ARG VIRTUAL_ENV
# tools needed to build psycopg from source:
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc python3-dev libpq-dev
# Copy dependencies list
COPY dependencies.txt dependencies.txt
# Create virtual enviroment without bootstrapped pip
RUN python -m venv --without-pip ${VIRTUAL_ENV}
# Install dependencies list
# --prefix used to install inside virtual enviroment path
# --use-pep517 used to solve https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
# "# DEPRECATION: psycopg2 is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed"
# https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pipca_install/#pip-install
RUN pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir pip \
    && pip install --prefix=${VIRTUAL_ENV} --no-cache-dir --use-pep517 --check-build-dependencies --requirement dependencies.txt \
    && pip cache purge

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} as runtime
ARG VIRTUAL_ENV
# Copy compiled run-time dependencies
COPY --from=build ${VIRTUAL_ENV} ${VIRTUAL_ENV}
# tools needed to build the Microsoft OBDC driver for Microsoft SQL server (requirements)
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gnupg curl gcc \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends msodbcsql17 \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unixodbc-dev \
    # clean up
    && apt-get purge -y gnupg curl gcc \
    && apt-get clean
# leverage layer caching by placing frequent-changing files down below the dockerfile (app files):
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app
# Copy all app files
COPY . .
# Use virtual enviroment (persistent in the final image):
ENV PATH=$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH
# Cannot unset so set to empty string (bad practice)
ENV PYTHONHOME=
# Executable to be run
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]
# default run to be overwritten with docker run command
CMD ["--help"]
```

To date, I install the packages I need in the final layer and then uninstall what I don't need, although it's not an elegant solution in my opinion. Also if you have any other inputs in order to learn more best practices, feel free to share. Thank you

Comment: Does `apt-get install msodbcsql17` really build the driver from source?  If so, what you have is probably the best you can get, but Debian packages usually contain precompiled binaries.

Comment: (Depending on how your application is packaged, you could potentially `RUN pip install .` into the virtual environment in the first stage, and if you have a setuptools entry point [different from a Docker entrypoint] then you can just run `CMD ["app"]` out of `$PATH`, without having to explicitly name the `python` interpreter.)

Comment: About building the debian packages from source, I don't really know. If that is not the case, as you suggested, and the package contain precompiled binaries should I change something?
The second point about not calling the python interpreter, I don't know what you are talking about. Can you reference me something to read in order to understand what is the point? Thank you

Comment: Do you need `gcc` at all in the final layer?  If removing it works, I might get rid of the `apt-get purge` line entirely; neither `curl` nor `gnupg` are that big.

Comment: I am almost sure I do need `gcc` in the final layer in order to install the `msodbcsql17` package but I can check. Anyway, I don't want to want to get rid of clean up routines as I want to learn how to optimize docker images. Next step would be to get rid of wheel, pip, setuptools and other system tools like system package manager and shells and go distroless. I need to learn how to install system packages and transfer them to the final layer though.

Comment: "Install system packages and transfer them to the final layer" is difficult to do, and essentially involves having a manifest of every file that gets installed or generated.  I probably wouldn't try to optimize an image to the point of removing a package manager (unless I was using a compiled language where I could run a `FROM scratch` image; Python is not that).

Comment: Thanks for the insights, would you mind sharing your idea on this approach also?
https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/issues/863
I will try to check if there are also options to compile scientific python libraries optimized for my app with reduced storage size